# Maven configuration error : repo.maven.apache.org

Tags: maven-2

I am trying to create a simple java project using maven.
But I am getting one error in the problems tab with the maven configuration.

The error description is "repo.maven.apache.org"

The error type is "maven configuration" problem.

Can any one help ?

Here is my pom.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.bhawani.sample.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>FirstSimpleSpringProject</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>FirstSimpleSpringProject</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Can you show your pom and the whole stacktrace?

Comment: Please refer to the pom above.

Comment: @BhawanishankarPanda Jens asked for the stacktrace and not the pom. Furthermore it sounds like you are working within Eclipse? Have you access directly to internet or do you need to go via a proxy? If yes you need to change your settings.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have not already tried, try to build your project from command prompt, you will get what exactly you are missing. Additionally, need to verify if provided local repository path has been provided and if you are building it offline/behind company proxy server, add proper proxy setting as well.